# Problems with Neumann (zero flux) boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I have the following code:

```
(*Parameters*)eps = 1.4434; m = 0.3; c11 = 0.1732; maxCellMeasure = \
0.1;
(*PDEs*)
pde11 := 
  D[pp[t, x], t] == 
   0.05*Laplacian[pp[t, x], {x}] + 
    pp[t, x]*(1 - c11*pp[t, x] - z[t, x]/(1 + pp[t, x]^2));
pde21 := D[z[t, x], t] == 
   0.05*Laplacian[z[t, x], {x}] + 
    z[t, x]*(eps*pp[t, x]/(1 + pp[t, x]^2) - m);
(*Initial conditions*)
lo = 48;
hi = 52;
domlen = 100;
ic11[x_] := Which[x > lo && x < hi, 6, True, 0];
ic21[x_] := Which[x < hi && x > lo, 0.5, True, 1/c11];
(*Numerical approximation using NDSolve with zero-flux boundary \
conditions*)
{solp, solz} = 
 Monitor[NDSolveValue[{pde11, pde21, z[0, x] == ic11[x], 
    pp[0, x] == ic21[x], (D[pp[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 
     0, (D[z[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 
     0, (D[pp[t, x], x] /. x -> domlen) == 
     0, (D[z[t, x], x] /. x -> domlen) == 0}, {pp, z}, {t, 29, 
    30}, {x, 0, domlen}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     MeshOptions -> MaxCellMeasure -> maxCellMeasure}, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])], monitor]
```

To be honest, I don't really understand the usage of NeumannValue. So, I implemented zero flux (zero Neumann) boundary conditions myself. However, I get the following error, which I don't understand:

```
NDSolveValues: The dependent variable in pp^(0,1)[t,0]==0 in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[pp^(0,1)[t,0]==0,x==0.`] needs to be linear.
```

Why is Mathematica writing something about DirichletConditions here?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: 1. `"FiniteElement"` method cannot parse b.c.s like `(D[z[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 
     0`, at least now. In other words, if you want to use **non-zero** Neumann condition in `"FiniteElement"`, you **have to** use `NeumannValue`. 2. However, the default setting for `"FiniteElement"` method is zero `NeumannValue`, in other words, you can just omit all of the zero Neumann condition in your code when using `"FiniteElement"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the reference page of [NeumannValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html), there you will find a note in the details section (and examples) that address your issue:

When no boundary condition is specified on a part of the boundary ∂Ω, then the flux term ∇·(-c ∇u-α u+γ)+… over that part is taken to be f=f+0=f+NeumannValue[0,…], so not specifying a boundary condition at all is equivalent to specifying a Neumann 0 condition.

This means that in order to specify a 0 flux you need to: nothing. So this does what you want:

```
(*Parameters*)eps = 1.4434; m = 0.3; c11 = 0.1732; maxCellMeasure = \
0.1;
(*PDEs*)
pde11 := 
  D[pp[t, x], t] == 
   0.05*Laplacian[pp[t, x], {x}] + 
    pp[t, x]*(1 - c11*pp[t, x] - z[t, x]/(1 + pp[t, x]^2));
pde21 := D[z[t, x], t] == 
   0.05*Laplacian[z[t, x], {x}] + 
    z[t, x]*(eps*pp[t, x]/(1 + pp[t, x]^2) - m);
(*Initial conditions*)
lo = 48;
hi = 52;
domlen = 100;
ic11[x_] := Which[x > lo && x < hi, 6, True, 0];
ic21[x_] := Which[x < hi && x > lo, 0.5, True, 1/c11];
(*Numerical approximation using NDSolve with zero-flux boundary \
conditions*)
{solp, solz} = 
 Monitor[NDSolveValue[{pde11, pde21, z[0, x] == ic11[x], 
    pp[0, x] == ic21[x]}, {pp, z}, {t, 29, 
    30}, {x, 0, domlen}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     MeshOptions -> MaxCellMeasure -> maxCellMeasure}, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])], monitor]
```

Also, note that there is a difference between a `NeuamannValue` and the derivative you specified. You can read up on that in the documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#1529668360). The finite element method parses your input as a `DirichletCondition` and lets you know that this is not a valid `DirichletCondition`.

Let me suggest that you read some of the finite element documentation. As an introduction you can read [Solving Partial Differential Equations with Finite Elements](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html).